# Is there an architecture/framework for desktop applications similar to S#arp archicture for web applications?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture

Is there any architecture or framework for Desktop applications similar to S#arp architecture for Web applications. S#arp Architecture uses Fluent NHibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try using S#arp Architecture for your WinForms project? S#arpArch is not necessarily tied to web development, although it has quite some web-flavors.

There are some guidelines in the S#arpArch wiki: http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/ContribNonWebHowTo.ashx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not as complete as S#arp, but [uNhAddIns](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/) has a good, reusable sample structure.

Check http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Examples/uNHAddIns.Examples.WPF

Another alternative is Effectus: http://github.com/ayende/Effectus